# unusual ethernet behaviour on win 7

Tags: windows-7, ethernet

I've returned home from uni, where my computer was on their network.  For authentication, they used IEEE 802.1x authentication, so I had to configure my NIC for this setting.

When I connect my computer to my home switch, the light switch light lights until the windows machine boots to the login prompt.

It then switches off, and shows network cable unplugged in  Network Connections.

I have disabled the IEEE 802.1x authentication and rebooted, but the same behaviour occurs.  I don't have another cable to try - is there anything I'm overlooking?

Comment: Check Device Manager, does your NIC show up OK?
Sounds like when it boots, it's working fine and the BIOS hands control over to Windows and sadly, Windows drops the ball.

Comment: Yeah, device manager says its working properly, hence the title for this question.  I'm going to test hardware by booting via USB drive to linux mint, but I'm fairly certain the hardware is good...  The mobo has two ethernet ports - same behaviour on both of them...

Comment: Silly question from my end but have you tried disabling it and then re-enabling it? Finally, you can *remove* the device via the Device Manager and then scan for hardware changes, which will reinstall the device. That will create a *new* NIC profile hopefully undoing any configuration that might have screwed it up.

Comment: Yeah, I tried that.  No change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have experienced some "misterious" issues with Windows networking before and found out that sometimes the only solution is to reset both TCP/IP and WinSock settings completely. You can try it by executing the Command Prompt as Administrator and running the following commands in it:

```
netsh interface ipv4 reset
netsh interface ipv6 reset
netsh winsock reset
```

Then reboot your computer and see if it helped.

You may also check the settings of the Network Adapter, in the Advanced tab, and see if the setting for "Speed & Duplex" is set to Auto. Having it forcing something that is not compatible with your Switch may cause it to not work at all and tell the cable is disconnected.

Comment: upvote requires 15 reputation, but thanks, I'll give that a try :)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure adapter settings are ok under network connections, also make sure you are not setup on a static IP. If this is still not working test with another network card if possible

Comment: Yep, I tried amending network configuration, although the NICs were setup to use DHCP.  No change.